# Pytest get environemnt from command line with simple-settings

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Given I have added this following piece of code in conftest.py:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--environment', action='store')
```

I have created a Stanging.py file that has :

```
URL = "Some URL"
```

And then I launch the tesets using:

```
pytest --environment "Staging"
```

How do I then get, in a separate file, the environment option's value?

I tried in my test file:

```
from simple_settings import settings
```

and then:

```
print(settings.URL)
```

But when executed it raised:

```
Settings are not configured
```

Comment: So if you want to use the settings set in the cmdline have a look here: https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/example/simple.html?highlight=custom%20options if you want to read values from an environment variable use `os.environ.get("variable_name")`